# Problems using py installer flask-desktop

Tags: python

I cannot generate my setup with pyInstaller. When I type command "pyinstaller -w -F myfile.py" here is error below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I2Fy.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. **The question should be written so that it makes sense even if the links break or change.** Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs more clarity/ detail. You should check that you have properly installed pyinstaller and python and that your python code runs without errors. If it still does not work, you can try running the same command on a different OS (e.g. on a Windows PC if possible)